# Freemarker: Boolean vs boolean get methods

Tags: java, freemarker

As it is known freemarkers beanwrapper uses the BeanIntrospector of java.  That has a consequence that wrapped Boolean cannot have an "is" method for it's public gets but just has to be a plain get method.

Now I'm working on a project where all of the sudden it became obvious primitive booleans had to become Boolean ...  Odd situation ofcourse but we are here.  Ofcourse all the freemarkers don't work anymore.

I was wondering if anyone knows, that there is somewhere on the net some BeanWrapper written for freemarker that doesn't use the BeanIntrospector but some other way to allow Booleans to have is method getters ?  Reason I'm asking is because I could try and write my own but the project just doesn't allow the time for it.  I have been googling for a while but can't come up with anything (mostly since google seems to take Boolean and boolean as the same word ...)

If there isn't any ... I'm just going to let one of the juniors change all is methods to get ... thats gonna be a fun task for that guy ...

Thanks in advance

Kenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't point to any solution that you can just download. But this is actually quite easy to do by overriding `finetuneMethodAppearance` in BeansWrapper. There you can make a fake property from any method. See the [related part of the JavaDocs](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/ext/beans/BeansWrapper.html#finetuneMethodAppearance%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.reflect.Method,%20freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.MethodAppearanceDecision%29).

OTOH, probably the best thing to do is changing those methods to `get` methods, because FreeMarker is not the only component that adheres to the JavaBeans spec. So, even if you fix this in FreeMarker, you can still run into the same problem elsewhere.

Comment: We went indeed for the set everything to get methods sollution, exactly for the reason you mention.  There will probably be other technologies that adhere to the spec.  I know for a fact we will use jasper in the future, I just don't want to think of the mess we would run into if jasper couldn't read is methods on wrapped booleans